# Why is the circle of convergence for complex power series a circle (and not e.g. a square)?

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, circles

Power-Series have an "circle of convergence".
With real numbers this is an interval.
Expanding this to complex numbers this becomes a circle.

There are lots of book stating this, but I did not find any which explained why this is a circle.

Thanks

Joe

Comment: Because the important thing is the absolute modulus, and the set of points with absolute modulus smaller than $r$ is a disk.

Comment: @DanielFischer "Absolute modulus"? We usually say "absolute value" when dealing with real numbers and "modulus" when dealing with complex numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know it as the radius of convergence, but it stems from how it is calculated.

Given a power series $\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_nx^n$, it is convergent if $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}x^{n+1}|}{|a_nx^n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}||x^{n+1}|}{|a_n||x^n|}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}|x|<1$$
Or 
$$ |x|<\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|a_n|}{|a_{n+1}|} $$

Note that, if $x=a+bi$ for $a,b\in\Bbb R$, then $|x|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}<L$, which has a locus of a disk.

Comment: The radius of convergence is **not** defined as the limit you write (which may not exist).

Comment: That's how I've seen it defined, how would you define it (If the limit doesn't exist, then isn't the radius $0$)?

Comment: "That's how I've seen it defined" OK, **where**? // *[The radius of convergence of a power series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) is the radius of the largest disk in which the series converges*.

Comment: Tim, you present a formula which is true for real numbers and uses the absolute value of real numbers. Then you write the definition for absolute values for complex numbers. Your reasoning ist: Just write a complex number instead of a real and the formula ist still truth. Why can we operate in the way you do?

Comment: Sorry, I should say that's how I've seen it calculated. Obviously you have an accurate definition on hand.

Comment: Did, that's the definition. This implies that outside the circle it my converge or not. But for power series the serie diverges outside the circle.

Comment: @Joe, the [proof of the ratio test](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Ratio_Test) works both in the real numbers and the complex numbers.

Comment: @Tim, the proof of the ratio test is the answer and uses the reason implicitly: because absolute value of complex numbers is defined in such a way that it shares all the properties of real numbers, esp.: abs(a)*abs(b)=abs(a*b).

Comment: @Joe Why are you spreading more confusion? Anybody taking the ratio test for the definition of the radius of convergence of a series should try their hands at $\sum\limits_nx^{2n}$.

Answer (score 1):

Assume the power series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ converges for some $z$; say for $z:=1$. Then the "numerical" series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k$ is convergent, which implies $\lim_{k\to \infty}|a_k|=0$, and in particular that there is an $M$ with $|a_k|\leq M$ for all $k\geq0$. It follows that the series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k$ is absolutely convergent in the disk $D_1:=\{z\in{\mathbb C}\>|\>|z|<1\}$.

From the above we can conclude that the domain $C$ of convergence is a union of concentric disks, one for each $z$, for which convergence has been established. This union is obviously again a (possibly infinite) open disk with radius
$$\rho:=\sup\bigl\{|z|\>\bigm|\>\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kz^k\ {\rm is\ convergent}\bigr\}\ .$$